# Ubuntu multi boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I am using windows 10 as the host operating system.

I was trying to use multi-boot due to Ubuntu.

Of the 256 gbs, 130 was allocated to the original Windows 10 operating system, and 130 was partitioned. I tried to put Ubuntu in a partition.

But when I tried to install it, there was a problem. When you boot your computer, it will only run in Ubuntu, and the existing Windows 130 Gbs mounted in Ubuntu.

How do I boot multi-boot?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I've done it:

```
$sudo os-prober
$sudo grub-install [devicename of your boot medium]
$sudo update-grub
```

To find which device is your boot medium:

```
$lsblk
```

the boot medium will be of the form "/dev/sda" but could be different. It won't be something like "/dev/sda1" because that's a partition and you want the drive under the partition.